C# UDP not responding
I am trying to talk with an arduino over UDP .
Tried with packetsender and arduino is reponding correctly .
I try to build C# for windows work pretty good but I am stuck on some parts .
My Mains ideas is to have windows software sending UDP message every 0.250 ms toward arduino and perform an action depending on arduino response .
it's short message on both direction
OR
listening the port 1234 at all time but sometimes I want to send message toward arduino .
Hope someone had more skill than me and can help me to fix it
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;

namespace control_drone
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //public static int listenPort = 1234;
       // private async Task Sending_Message(String text_to_sendd)
        //{
         public void Sending_Message(String text_to_sendd)
        { 
            //await Task.Run(() =>
            //{
              //  byte[] data;
                Socket sending_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                IPAddress send_to_address = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.126");
                IPEndPoint sending_end_point = new IPEndPoint(send_to_address, 1234);
                byte[] send_buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text_to_sendd);
                sending_socket.SendTo(send_buffer, sending_end_point);

# This parts below work great except if a the arduino is not connected the software freeze 

             //   IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
               // EndPoint Remote = (EndPoint)(sender);

                //data = new byte[256];
                //int recv = sending_socket.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);
                //string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
                //test1.Text = response;
                //this.Text = response;

                
          //  });
            
             }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ReceiveMessage();
           //StartListener();
           //UDPListener();
           // ListenOnport();
           //Broadcast_to_arduino();        
        }

// seems to me that this parts doesn't work at all 
            private async Task ReceiveMessage()
            {
                using (var udpClient = new UdpClient(1234))
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        var receivedResult = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync();
                    string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedResult.Buffer);
                    this.Text = text;
                }
            }
            }
        







        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         }


        private void D1H_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //ReceiveMessage();
            Sending_Message("Yellow hovering");
            //this.Text=
         //   UDPListener();
            //Broadcast_to_arduino();

        }

        private void D1RTH_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Sending_Message("COMPUTERPR");
        }

        private void D2H_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Sending_Message("COMPUTERYH");
        }

        private void D2RTH_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Sending_Message("COMPUTERYR");
        }

        private void D3H_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Sending_Message("COMPUTERGH");
        }

        private void D3RTH_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Sending_Message("COMPUTERGR");
        }

        private void D4H_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Sending_Message("COMPUTERWH");
        }

        private void D4RTH_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Sending_Message("COMPUTERWR");
        }

        private void Green(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            splitContainer1.Panel2.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
        }

        private void split2_panel1_new_colour(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            splitContainer2.Panel2.BackColor= Color.Blue;
        }

        private void split2_panel2_new_colour(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}

work pretty good except if the arduino is diconnected or not responding ,my windows software freeze and I had to restart .
Below is the arduino code who is working well so far only the windows software doesn't work as expected

#include "WiFi.h"
#include "AsyncUDP.h"

const char *ssid =  "";
const char *password = "";

int button1=3;
int button2=2;
int relay=9;



AsyncUDP udp;

void setup() {
pinMode(button1, INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode(button2, INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode(button1, OUTPUT); //need for seed arduino
pinMode(button2, OUTPUT); //need for seed arduino


Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  if (WiFi.waitForConnectResult() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("WiFi Failed");
    while (1) {
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
  if (udp.listen(1234)) {
    Serial.print("UDP Listening on IP: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    Serial.println("UDP connected");
    udp.onPacket([](AsyncUDPPacket packet) {
      //Serial.print(", Data: ");
      //Serial.write(packet.data());
      //Serial.println();
      //reply to the client
      //packet.printf("Got %u bytes of data", packet.data());
      //packet.print("Hello Server");
      //packet.broadcastTo("Anyone", 1234);
     
     //button 
     
     int Lastsate;
int state1=digitalRead(button1);
int state2=digitalRead(button2);
     if(state1 == 1 && (state2 == 0))
{

//Serial.print("first side is pressed:  ");
//Serial.println(state1);
packet.print("first side is pressed");
//packet.print("button number 2");
//digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
Lastsate=0;
}

if(state2 == 1 && (state1 == 0)){
//Serial.print("button number 2:  ");
//Serial.println(state2);
packet.print("button number 2");
//digitalWrite(relay, LOW);
Lastsate=0;

}
// for esp32C3 seeed value need to be 0
if(state1 == 0 && (state2 == 0)){
//Serial.println("well there is no winnerrrrr");
packet.print("No button pressed");
Lastsate=1;

}
//button parts

    });
    //Send unicast
    //udp.print("Hello Server!");
  //udp.broadcastTo("Anyone", 1234);
  }
}

void loop() {
  delay(1000);
 Serial.println("new line");
  //Send broadcast on port 1234
 // udp.broadcastTo("Anyone here?", 1234);
}

I try different code from internet and seems to me that no one works as the arduino response doesn't appear on the textbox but the arduino receive the command because I saw it on the serials and also work well with packet sender on both way

It is probably a timeout issue.  You have a long timeout waiting for a connection which hangs up the software.  Decreasing the connection timeout should solve issue.

You need to dispose the socket once you are done, it's probably preventing you reopening it

How can i dispose the socket after use ?
